# How can I get JSON data from the instagram user info page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, instagram

[instagram.com/username/?__a=1](https://instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1) gives data about a user in JSON format, where username can be substituted for any username.

I'm trying to copy the user's logging page id number, which is written  *"logging_page_id":"profilePage_xxxxxxxx"* on the webpage. To circumvent cross-origin-policy, I'm using the allorigins CORS proxy.
This is my current code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    


<script> $.get('https://api.allorigins.win/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1'), function (data) {
console.log(data);
           });
```

This script returns some irrelevant code, I think from some other instagram page. How can I change my code to get the info I'm looking for? Or is it impossible to do what I want using frontend languages only?

(first post, sorry if I made any etiquette mistakes)

Comment: That looks like instagram's 404 page, but since it's being proxied through allorigins, I can't see the original headers. It's possible that instagram is detecting and blocking attempts by allorigins to query that route. When I try it in node, I get redirected.

Comment: I think you need to be signed in to instagram for the link to work

Comment: I'm not signed into instagram in any context, but I get data in chrome, but not in node.

Comment: yep, I think you're right. I just tried it with another JSON file and everything worked out fine. Instagram is probably blocking the request. I think Instagram thinks the request by a bot so it gives the 429 error